# Convert Grayscale 2D Image to Rectangular Mesh

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to create a rectangular mesh for fluid flow analysis by importing a grayscale image of an obstacle and converting it to a mesh of fluid cells and boundary cells.  I think the best way to do this is to iterate through the pixels of the image and determine whether the pixel value is black (boundary) or white (fluid).  I would need to map this to a N x M mesh that I would specify in my code (preferably in an array that has either C_B for cell boundary and C_F for cell fluid.

Any help for implementing this in either Matlab or Mathematica?

**sample image**
[image]

Comment: this is a great question. could be fun. Do you have a sample image?

Comment: Here is my image.  It's an ahmed body configuration (standard for simulating vehicle aerodynamics) 

http://imgur.com/5T6IagP

Comment: I think the solution i posted should work well for this image. And in matlab a mesh and matrix are really the same thing. So once you converted your image to grayscale/binary you are free to do whatever you want. You may need to convert it to a double (or some other data type) this is simply done with this step `double_im = double(my_gray_image);`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion definitely helped.  I was able to import the picture and identify white and black cells easily by converting it to a binary image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you want to do a binarization of your image. In matlab this is simple (I'm sure its easy in mathematica as well but I don't know the software)

this is a very rough outline and this also uses the `Image Processing toolbox`

```
%this automatically creates a threshold for your data. it assumes your
%intensities are bimodal distribution, and tries to split them and minimize
%the overlap suing something called "otsu's algorithm" the result is a     
%normalized value between 0 and 1
my_thresh = graythresh(my_gray_image);

%create your binary image. im assuming your image is uint8 type 0-255 
%since our threshold is between 0,1 we must multiply by 255 to get the
%uint8 threshold
binary_im  = im2bw(my_gray_im, round(my_thresh*255));

%displays the images
figure()
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(my_gray_im);title('original image')
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(binary_im  );title('binary image')
```

the result is cells that are either 0 or 1, so it wouldnt exactly be C_B and C_F but its the same idea